# htaccess rewrite from a php file to subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect from `example.com/profile.php?UserName=xxxx` to `xxxx.example.com`
xxxx contains a-z or 0-9.
I have tried bunch of codes to do it (some from this site) but none of them worked as I wanted it to be. Here is my current code:

```
RewriteEngine on
#this should redirect example.com/profile.php?UserName=x to x.site.com 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-_]+).example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) %1/$1 [QSA,L]

#if link does not contain subdomain add www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You want to `xxxx.example.com` to show the content of `www.example.com/profile.php?UserName=xxxx`. Right?

Comment: yes ... but xxxx is changing and may contain english lowercase letters and numbers only.

Comment: What happens if you remove the last two rewrite rules and try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was not a good answer here.. In order to rename a php file and use the subdomain extention.. I had to edit my DNS settings.. This tutorial helped :http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/server/apache/mod-rewrite/subdomains.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all of your redirect rules **before** your internal routing rules. The rules with the `R` flag redirect.

```
RewriteEngine on

# This redirects the browser to include the "www"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# This redirects the browser when profile.php is directly accessed
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+profile\.php\?UserName=([a-z0-9-_]+)
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.example.com/? [L,R]

# this internally routes the XXX.example.com to the profile.php script
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-_]+).example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /profile.php?UserName=%1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: when accessing : example.com/profile.php?UserName=something
I get redirected to : http://something.example.com/?UserName=something. How do you remove the ?UserName=something

Comment: something.example.com is not displaying the page example.com/profile.php?UserName=Something I tried to switch to R=301 it is still doing the same thing.